# What is the purpose of starting Activity in postdelayed method

Tags: android, android-activity

When starting an activity from an activity's create method. Does it make any difference if an activity is started directly started as in below

```
  startActivityForResult(..)
```

versus

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(() -> startActivityForResult(..)
```

Why should an activity be started through post delayed method ?

Comment: It actually depends on your use case. 
What is your use case?

Answer (score 1):

If you need some delay before starting a new activity, then `postDelayed()` is an answer, otherwise, you do not need to use.

Some useful conditions when you may need a delay to start an activity

- Pin code, when you fill correctly inform the user all four input is taken
- Await for ending of some animation
- Splash screen at the welcome page

Answer (score 1):

postDelayed() is actually used in order to delay the certain task for specific amount of time. Actually the proper use of postDelayed would be

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
              //Your code with startactivity

            }
        }, DELAY_DURATION);
```

Here, the DELAY_DURATION is the amount of time in millisecond that you want to delay. Mostly this is used in case of splash screen. Lets say, if the DELAY_DURATION is 5000, then your code inside run block will run after 5 secs.